# Clean remotes/origin/master branch after deleting remote repository

Tags: git, git-remote

I have deleted my github repository but still want to keep versions on my local.

However, I still have `remotes/origin/master` branch when I run `git branch -a`.

I want to get rid of remote branches but when I try to;

```
git pull --prune

remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/EfeBudak/InterestCalculator.git/' not found
```

How can I remove remote branches even if the remote repository does no longer exist?

Answer (score 1):

so... lets confirm, that in the beggining you have something like this:

```
noisy@t440s ~/devel/gitschool
$ git remote 
origin

noisy@t440s ~/devel/gitschool
$ git remote -v
origin  git@myserver.com:noisy/gitschool.git (fetch)
origin  git@myserver.com:noisy/gitschool.git (push)

noisy@t440s ~/devel/gitschool
$ git remote add backup git@myserver.com:noisy/gitschool_backup.git

$ git remote -v
origin  git@myserver.com:noisy/gitschool.git (fetch)
origin  git@myserver.com:noisy/gitschool.git (push)
backup  git@myserver.com:noisy/gitschool_backup.git (fetch)
backup  git@myserver.com:noisy/gitschool_backup.git (push)
```

... and later

```
noisy@t440s ~/devel/gitschool
$ git fetch --all
Fetching origin
remote: Counting objects: 44, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (44/44), done.
remote: Total 44 (delta 18), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (44/44), done.
From myserver.com:noisy/gitschool
 * [new branch]      T16 -> origin/T16
Fetching backup
From myserver.com:noisy/gitschool_backup
 * [new branch]      T16 -> backup/T16
 * [new branch]      master     -> backup/master
```

and finally you have deleted your `backup` repository... but `git branch -r` still gives:

```
noisy@t440s ~/devel/gitschool
$ git branch -r
  origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  origin/T16
  origin/master
  backup/T16
  backup/master
```

In my case, after removing remote `backup`...

```
noisy@t440s ~/devel/gitschool
$ git remote rm backup
```

I see only branches on my current remote :)

```
noisy@t440s ~/devel/gitschool
$ git branch -r
  origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  origin/T16
  origin/master
```

Comment: It was hard to read because the solution part is not marked by formatting. I could only find it because I know what to seek for, i.e. I know the solution already :)

Comment: git fetch --all
Fetching origin
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/EfeBudak/InterestCalculator.git/' not found
error: Could not fetch origin
Fetching backup
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/EfeBudak/InterestCalculator_backup.git/' not found
error: Could not fetch backup

Answer (score 0):

You can use the  [git remote rm](https://help.github.com/articles/removing-a-remote/) command:

```
$git remote rm [remote name]
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Though worded as a question, this is definitely an answer.

Comment: @Logan Yes, this is a valid and full answer.

Comment: @NickVolynkin thanks, I was just in doubt because it seemed too simple. I don't why this wasn't marked as an answer though.